# .htaccess Add a parameter to query string if using certain subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to add a fixed parameter to a URL if a certain sub domain is used, but otherwise leave the URL untouched.
For example:
http://subdomain.domain.com?foo=bar

would rewrite to
http://subdomain.domain.com?foo=bar&isMySub=true

but http://domain.com?foo=bar or http://othersubdomain.domain.com?foo=bar would remain untouched.

Ive looked around on here and so far all Ive been able to ascertain is that it will likely require the [QSA] flag so as to leave the rest of the query string intact.

This get me close, but some links and images break so it has to be messing up my url or query in ways I dont want.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com(&|$)
RewriteRule .* index.php?foo=bar [QSA]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude requests for certain files using the `%{REQUEST_URI}` server variable and checking the extension:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com
RewriteRule .* index.php?isMySub=true [QSA]
```

The `[QSA]` flag will pass the existing query string, such as `?foo=bar`, so you don't have to.

Alternative rules for the above ruleset:

Send to *index.php* and add requested resource as the query variable `req`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?req=$1&isMySub=true [QSA]
```

The parenthesis `()` in the rule pattern capture the matching value into a variable. First set of parens goes to `$1`, second to `$2`, etc.

Or, send to same resource as is requested but with the added query variable.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?isMySub=true [QSA]
```

Comment: Why does it break images to begin with though, this rule should only be adding a parameter to the query string which shouldn't break any images `sub.domain.com\img.jpg?MySub=true` should still return `sub.domain.com\img.jpg`, it does without the rule.

Comment: Actually without the exclusion the images would be rewritten to `sub.domain.com/index.php?MySub=true`.

Comment: ok, that sheds some light. Is there any way to append a querystring without directly referencing the file? or turn the file itself into a variable? like %{REQUEST_FILENAME}?isMySub=true

Comment: The last example in your edit was perfect! This thing is going on a joomla site which already has all kinds of rewrites for SEO and stuff, hence the reason I had to do my best to leave the actual URL unedited except for the additional query.